# MySQL: non-subordinative self relationship

Tags: mysql

Usually in self realtionship tutorials it is taught in a subordinative way. Eg.: employee X subordinated to employee Y.

I have this scenario bellow where the related players are actually the same person but with different accounts.

So I don't know whether this is right to use self relationship in this case.

(aka: also known as)

aka_id ----> id_player

One player account is not subordinated to another. Players can have multiple accounts but I'm willing to relate them so I can tell they belong to the same person. In the real scenario, there is no master account to relate them to. this is a NON-SUBURDINATIVE scenario.

[image]

I thought of not using relationship in this case and insert a random hash key tag to the aka column:

```
380 | player120 | ae65a3f01a
500 | player430 | ae65a3f01a
```

The question here is:

Is it right to use self relationships in **non-subordinative** scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

From the way you describe the problem, you have two entities:  players and aka (which I will call nicknames).  These are two separate entities, and that usually suggests three tables:

- Players
- Nicknames
- PlayerNicknames

The third table is a junction table that combines the first two.  You might be able to put all the information you need about Nicknames in PlayerNicknames -- that is fine.  However, if you have a requirement that all nick names be unique, then you definitely want a third table.

My guess is that you have a player name that is automatically a nick name.  Great.  When you create a player, also create an entry in the nicknames.

Comment: Well noted, but this is an hypothetical situation. The nickNames/playerNames may be the same. Otherwise I could use your solution.